# How link multiple dimensions

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

I am trying to pull data for below fields with ETL and build a custom report. I can pull at max only 7 fields using ETL (Pentaho PDI) at a time. Is there a way to link these dimensions (User, Traffic Sources, Geo Netwrok) using a unique key like Surrogate Key after extracting data? Thanks in advance.

```
ga:source        <-User
ga:sourceMedium  <-User
ga:userType      <-User
ga:sessionCount  <-User
ga:campaign         <-Traffic Sources
ga:adDestinationUrl <-Traffic Sources
ga:keyword          <-Traffic Sources
ga:city            <-Geo Network 
ga:userAgeBracket  <-Audience
```

Comment: There is no key that will let you link two requests to each other.  My only work around has been to add ga:date to all the requests and use that as my reference.  However this still doesn't work completely.  avgusers from one request wont be the same as avg user from the second request.

Comment: Not for existing data, but you could modify your tracking code to store the client id from the cookie as a custom dimension so you'd have a key for newly incoming data.

Comment: I agree with Eike - but I'd add to tracking sessionId,clientId,userId and TimeStamp in custom dimensions and this repairs many shortcomings of the Google analytics schema and allows flexible retrieval

Comment: You can simplify your query to the 7 dimensions.  sourceMedium includes source, so source is redundant.  userType is New for the first session of a user (where SessionCount==1), so that is also redundant.  That drops you to 7 dimensions.